# use patches diffusion in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

(happy new year)

I am trying to use diffuse patch-variable in Netlogo. I wrote this little script in order to diffuse energy in all patches. Unfortunately, I don't really get what I expect. I want to diffuse randomly energy according to one rate in all the patches. I also know that `scale-color` is helpful for see the change as observer but I not sure that it works.

Thanks

```
patches-own [energy]


to setup
clear-all
ask patches [set energy 0]
reset-ticks
end


to go
diffuse energy random 0.3
recolor
tick
end

to recolor
ask patches [set pcolor scale-color blue energy 0 10]
end
```

I saw in Netlogo dictionary that we can also take in account the neighbors. It will be interesting to se both possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line

```
Diffuse energy random 0.3
```

always comes out 0 because random reports (returns) integers. 
try

```
Diffuse energy random-float 0.3
```

That makes the patches diffuse a random rate on [0,0.3] every tick. All of them diffusing the same rate in any given tick. This is unusual but totally legal. Most often people set it to a constant on the interval (0,1)

Diffuse will not do any thing unless your patches have different values for the diffusing varible. Are you manually setting them? if not change your GO to

```
to go
 ask one-of patches [set energy 10]
 diffuse energy random 0.3
 recolor
 tick
end
```

You will see a better show.

Comment: Exactly what I expected. Thanks